# Cases where bit-fields are useful?

Tags: c, bit-fields

Which are the cases where bit-fields are useful?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: This is something that would be interesting, especially to learn about the operations that can be cone on these fields (e.g. Why would someone 'bitfield & bitfield')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Comment: The edited version is now a make-a-list question: not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Any case where you have several Boolean values that you want to store and you don't want to waste memory.

For example, a 32-bit integer has 32 bits. So you could use it to store 32 bit Boolean values using bit fields. Any other data structure would use 32 bytes at the very least.

Comment: I suggested an edit to also mention the performance benefits,... operating on 32 or 64 flag "variables" simultaneously using bitwise operations

Answer (score 1):

Roddy's answer has a nice explanation here

[Bitfield manipulation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044654/bitfield-manipulation-in-c)

- Bitfields are more succinct to use
  (at the expense of /slightly/ more
  verbosity to write.
- Bitfields are
  more robust (what size is "int",
  anyway)
- Bitfields are usually just
  as fast as bitwise operators.
- Bitfields are very powerful when you
  have a mix of single and multiple bit
  fields, and extracting the
  multiple-bit field involves loads of
  manual shifts.
- Bitfields are
  effectively self-documenting. By
  defining the structure and therefore
  naming the elements, I know what it's
  meant to do.
- Bitfields also seamlessly handle structures bigger than a single int.
- With bitwise operators, typical (bad) practice is a slew of #defines for the bit masks.
- The only caveat with bitfields is to make sure the compiler has really packed the object into the size you wanted. I can't remember if this is define by the standard, so a assert(sizeof(myStruct) == N) is a useful check.

Also go through [When is it worthwhile to use bit fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240974/when-is-it-worthwhile-to-use-bit-fields) , which has some nice examples.