# Colon : used in variable initialization?

Tags: c++

I found this line [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Properties/index.html):

```
uint32 bIsHungry : 1;
```

... and I've never seen this syntax used to initialize a variable.

I'm used to seeing this:

```
uint32 bIsHungry = 1;
```

It looks kind of like an initialization list, but for a single field?

What is it, what does it do, why should I care?

Comment: To initialize a scalar variable you can use either the equality sign or parentheses or braces.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That line is a [bit field declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) and it declares a data member with an explicit bit-level size

Example from cppreference:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
 // three-bit unsigned field,
 // allowed values are 0...7
 unsigned int b : 3;
};
int main()
{
    S s = {7};
    ++s.b; // unsigned overflow
    std::cout << s.b << '\n'; // output: 0
}
```

Notice that in the example above the unsigned overflow is [defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is) (same doesn't apply if `b` were declared as a signed type)

The documentation you links also states that

> Boolean types can be represented either with the C++ bool keyword or as a bitfield

Regarding *why should I care* I recommend reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4240974/1938163)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks, I've literally never seen that before.

Comment: It might come in handy under particular circumstances where e.g. the hardware will map at bit level parts of a memory area.

Answer (score 2):

This is bitfield declaration, Declares a class data member with explicit size, in bits.

Comment: There is neither initialization.

Answer (score 2):

It is not initialization, it is a fragment of a declaration.

```
struct {
    // ...
    uint32 bIsHungry : 1;
    // ...
};
```

declares a `bIsHungry` as a bitfield member of the `struct`. It says that `bIsHungry` is an `unsigned int` whose length is `1` bit. Its possible values are `0` and `1`.

Read more about bitfields: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field