# What does ':' mean in struct field declarations?

Tags: c++

Today, I saw an example in [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) website which was new to me. The provided example is as follow:

```
struct S {
    char a;     // memory location #1
    int b : 5;  // memory location #2
    int c : 11, // memory location #2 (continued)
          : 0,
        d : 8;  // memory location #3
    struct {
        int ee : 8; // memory location #4
    } e;
} obj; // The object 'obj' consists of 4 separate memory locations
```

I'm a little bit confused about the ':' in this example, what does "int b : 5;" mean in this example?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: This is a feature you will likely very rarely use.

Comment: Exactly, I'd never seen anybody use that before.

Comment: Not a duplicate but related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240974/when-is-it-worthwhile-to-use-bit-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240974/when-is-it-worthwhile-to-use-bit-fields)